# is it possible to pass promises to other middleware and have it resolve there?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-promise

I am trying to write common function that can handle promises.

So I have promises in main.ts and once request comes in i want to pass promises to common function to execute these with Promise.all

I am getting empty array of promises in commonFunction. Got kind of stuck here need help to achieve this task.

#### main.ts

```
 public async execute(@Request() request: express.Request): Promise < [any] | any > {
     const promises: any = [];
     promises.push.apply(this.getAccountDetails(request), this.getCardDetails(request));
     return responseCollector(request, promises);
 }

 @Post('getAccountDetails')
 private async getAccountDetails(@Body() request: any): Promise < any > {
     const accountDetails: any = await axios.post(
        url, request.body);

   return accountDetails; 
 }

 @Post('getCardDetails')
 private async getCardDetails(@Body() request: any): Promise < any > {

     // process cardDetails Call and get response 
 }
```

#### commonFunction.ts

```
 export function responseCollector(expressReq, promises) {
     console.log("requestBody>>>", expressReq.body);
     console.log("promioses>>>>", JSON.stringify(promises));

     if (expressReq.body.lob === "credit") {
         return promises.Object
     }
     if (expressReq.body.lob === "account") {
         return promises.object
     }

     return Promise.all(promises)

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public async execute(@Request() request: express.Request): Promise < [any] | any > {
     const promises: any = [];
     promises.push(this.getAccountDetails(request), this.getCardDetails(request));
     return responseCollector(request, promises);
}
```

Don't use `.apply`

Comment: `promioses>>>> [{},{}]
(node:12376) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): #<Object>
` still not getting promises in commonFunction

Comment: This is because you are trying to print a promise before you are trying to await on it.

Comment: Can you provide an example with the fix please , i added how i am handling promise in the question?

Comment: @hussain there is no fix, it is just a warning, you can ignore it safely. If you remove log, it will not give you any warning.

Comment: i was trying to see the object so i can execute each of those promises inside if conditions not sure how to do it without looking at it .